# Ubuntu Backup Cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I was wondering if someone could give me a quick script that I could run via cron that would backup my entire /var/www directory? I just want it to run once a day at 3:05am, and to put the copy in /media/sadisa/a_backup/engine/ . It'd be great if it could rename it to the time, like /media/sadisa/a_backup/engine/20100818_0305/www or something like that, but just www(1) www(2), etc would also work.

Thanks so much!

- Josh

Comment: Check out http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tarball with gzip-compression:**

```
tar czf /media/sadisa/a_backup/engine/`date +%F`/var-www-`date +%F`.tgz /var/www/
```

**Plain files & folders:**

```
mkdir /media/sadisa/a_backup/engine/`date +%F`/
cp -a /var/www/ /media/sadisa/a_backup/engine/`date +%F`/var-www-`date +%F`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE_HASH = $(echo -n `date` | openssl md5)
tar cvzf backup.tgz /var/www/
mv backup.tgz /backup_folder/${DATE_HASH}.tgz
```

Edit: I clearly don't remember why I wrote that part. Update as recommended in the comments:

```
BACKUP_DATETIME=$(echo -n $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M))
tar cvzf backup.tgz /var/www/
mv backup.tgz /backup_folder/${BACKUP_DATETIME}.tgz
```

Comment: No spaces around the equal sign. Why not use a human readable date? Why not use `$()` within `$()` instead of backticks?

Comment: That wasn't a date hash - it's YYYYMMDD_HHMM which you can get date to print with the format argument.  The reason he's doing that is cause it's sortable without jumping thru hoops.

Comment: That wasn't a date hash - it's `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M` .  The reason he's doing that is cause it's sortable without jumping thru hoops.

Comment: I don't unterstand, why you do that "echo `date` | openssl md5"? Coul'd you explain it?

Comment: How about: DATE_HASH = $(echo -n `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`) ... and maybe a better name than DATE_HASH since it is no longer a hash... :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Use [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use proper backup software to do the trick. I use [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/), which works really well. Very configurable.